# How to edit an HTML slider to make it like this?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a slider go from 1-999 stepping by 1, then from 1k to 5m stepping 1k, looking like this

```
1 2 3------999|1k-2k-3k----999k|1m-2m---5m
```

I have a code setup that goes from 1k to 5m, I want to add from 1 to 999 in a nice way at the start of the slider, but I cant make it.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h5 class="font-alt mt-30">Number of Followers</h5>
        <div class="price-input">
            <div class="field">
                <input readonly
                       class="input-min" value="0"
                       name="followers-min">
            </div>
            <div class="separator">-</div>
            <div class="field">
                <input readonly
                       class="input-max" value="INFINITY"
                       name="followers-max">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="range-input">
            <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="range" class="range-min" min="0"
                   max="5000000"
                   value="0"
                   step="1000">
            <input style="cursor: pointer;" type="range" class="range-max" min="0"
                   max="5000000"
                   value="5000000"
                   step="1000">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My current javascript

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input"),
    priceInput = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input input"),
    range = document.querySelectorAll(".slider .progress");
let priceGap = 100_000;

rangeInput.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput[0].value),
                maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput[1].value);

            if ((maxVal - minVal) < priceGap) {
                if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
                    rangeInput[0].value = maxVal - priceGap
                } else {
                    rangeInput[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
                }
            } else {

                let temp = 0
                let addition = ""

                if (minVal < 1_000) {
                    temp = String(minVal)
                } else if (minVal >= 1_000 && minVal < 10_000) {
                    temp = String(minVal)[0]
                    addition = "K"
                } else if (minVal >= 10_000 && minVal < 100_000) {
                    temp = String(minVal)[0] + String(minVal)[1]
                    addition = "K"
                } else if (minVal >= 100_000 && minVal < 1_000_000) {
                    temp = String(minVal)[0] + String(minVal)[1] + String(minVal)[2]
                    addition = "K"
                } else if (minVal >= 1_000_000) {
                    temp = String(minVal)[0]
                    addition = "M"
                }

                let tempMax = 0
                let additionMax = ""
                if (maxVal >= 1_000 && maxVal < 10_000) {
                    tempMax = String(maxVal)[0]
                    additionMax = "K"
                } else if (maxVal >= 10_000 && maxVal < 100_000) {
                    tempMax = String(maxVal)[0] + String(maxVal)[1]
                    additionMax = "K"
                } else if (maxVal >= 100_000 && maxVal < 1_000_000) {
                    tempMax = String(maxVal)[0] + String(maxVal)[1] + String(maxVal)[2]
                    additionMax = "K"
                } else if (maxVal >= 1_000_000) {
                    tempMax = String(maxVal)[0]
                    additionMax = "M"
                }

                if (maxVal === 5000000) {
                    priceInput[1].value = "INFINITY";
                } else {
                    priceInput[1].value = Number(tempMax) + additionMax;
                }

                priceInput[0].value = Number(temp) + addition;
                range[0].style.left = ((minVal / rangeInput[0].max) * 100) + "%";
                range[0].style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
            }
        }
    )
    ;
});
```

Any idea on how to add from 1-999 at the first of the slider so that it looks a bit like the slider on that website?
https://inflact.com/tools/instagram-search/

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally adjust the `step` attribute depending on the current value.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

slider.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  if (value < 2500) {
    slider.setAttribute("step", 1);
  } 
  else if (value >= 2500 && value < 5000) {
    slider.setAttribute("step", 100);
  } 
  else if (value >= 5000) {
    slider.setAttribute("step", 500);
  }

  output.value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<main>
  <label for="slider">Slider</label>
  <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="10000" step="1">
  <output name="output" for="slider">0</output>
</main>
```

Comment: I want to make the slider speed slow when I’m smaller numbers, so I can control it better. Any idea on how?

Comment: Please check the website I added, because it doesnt work as requested still

Comment: @MazenTayseer I looked at the website before answering the question. My intention wasn't to give you a production ready implementation but rather a simple example that you could use as a reference. If you want someone to code it for you, there are other sites for that kind of thing.

Comment: As far as slowing down the slider for smaller numbers - I'm not sure. If your slider is going from 0 to 1,000,000 or more, that's a lot of numbers. So probably what you'd want to do is increase the step amount for larger numbers so that there is more space available to the smaller numbers. If that makes sense. But again, I'm not really sure on that.